# Recursive Function To Find Determinant

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I'm trying to build a recursive function to calculate determinant using [Laplace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion).

```
function y=detm(M)
    n=length(M);

    if n==2
        y=M(1,1).*M(2,2)-(M(1,2).*M(2,1));
    else
       for i=1:n
           y=sum(((-1)^(1+n).*M(1,n).*detm(M([1:n-1,n+1:end],[1:n- 1,n+1:end]))));
    end
end
```

The issue is that I can not find a way to omit the need of the for loop as I need to run on the columns from 1 to n.
Is there a way to do it in the same function or I need to create another recursive function?

Comment: What is the question? A loop is not inherently bad, you can work with it. Why not use `det`?

Comment: @AnderBiguri That is my assignment

Comment: Why not just another recursive function with argument `i`?

Comment: OK. So what is your question really? We will not answer "how to do it", as it is homework, but if you clarify what is your problem and what do you want you might get help. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @AnderBiguri I know, I am just looking for a lead, I have a problem with the "for loop" and looking for way/hints to approach it

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I have looked into this a bit, you mean 2 independent recursive function or a recursive function that calls another recursive function?

Comment: A separate recursive function which takes the place of the `for`-loop. Also, the loop code does not depend on `i` which seems wrong, and it overwrites `y` every time.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I know that the for loop does not work well, I just tried to "show" what is my problem

Comment: So you are looking for an `O(n!)` algorithm when `O(n^3)` floating pointl and `O(n^4)` rational number algorithms are available.

Comment: Each call of detM for nxn matrices need to make n calls of detM for (n-1)*(n-1) matrices and sum up the results. The normal way is to use a for-loop, but you could use another recursive function as suggested by @meowgoesthedog